# PDO unbuffered queries in MODX

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, modx-revolution, xpdo

There are many line in my MODX error log stating that SQL queries have failed because unbuffered queries are active. The error line is like this:

`Cannot execute queries while other unbuffered queries are active.  Consider using PDOStatement::fetchAll().  Alternatively, if your code is only ever going to run against mysql, you may enable query buffering by setting the PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_USE_BUFFERED_QUERY attribute.`

I have understood that the default setting is that the queries are buffered in PDO? Can I modify this setting somewhere in MODX?

The site is working quite normally so this is not a severe issue.

Comment: Queries are buffered by default, perhaps implicitly apply it when you instance PDO with `setAttriubte(\PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_USE_BUFFERED_QUERY => true)`

Comment: MODX opens the xPDO connection automatically so I can't modify the code itself. I have tried to find out if MODX has a setting related to this. This problem actually occurred after I change the hosting provider.